# How to scrape all the childs of an element

Tags: javascript

I am scraping some HTML code as shown below, but the problem is that there is exactly 5 `.group` elements in my HTML code and each of them consists of 10 `.name-top` and `.name-bottom elements`. Query selector only returns the first child... What is the possible way of scraping all the elements with `.name` class and pushing all these items into the array?

```
var groups = document.getElementsByClassName('group');
  var matches = [];

  var arr = Array.from(groups).map(i => {
  const league = i.querySelector('.group-header').innerText;
  const name = i.querySelector('.name.top').innerText + " - " + i.querySelector('.name.bottom').innerText;

  matches.push({name : name, league : league});

  });
```

Comment: thats because it is supposed to return 1 try querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

use document.querySelectorAll to select all groups

```js
var groups = document.querySelectorAll('.group');
var matches = [];

var arr = Array.from(groups).map(i => {
  const league = i.querySelector('.group-header').innerText;
  const name = i.querySelector('.name.top').innerText + " - " + i.querySelector('.name.bottom').innerText;

  matches.push({name : name, league : league});
});
```

Comment: and what exactly is the difference between getElementsByClassName and QuerySelectorAll? Should do the same... @SWAPNIL KUWAR

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns live DOM elements,
querySelectorAll doesn't return live DOM elements. If Dom changed then it won't be reflected in the NodeList returned by querySelectorAll.